# how to make the menu sticked and don't be moved when changing the browser or the zoom

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, css-float, liquid-layout

Q:

I have a navigation menu ,i notice that every time i change the browser zoom. its position changed.how to make the menu fixed in its place.

the .css:

```
ul#topnav
{
    margin-left:0;

    margin-bottom:50px;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 800px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative; /*--Set relative positioning on the unordered list itself - not on the list item--*/
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background:#CC6A11; /*url(topnav_stretch.gif) repeat-x;*/
}
ul#topnav li
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #555; /*--Divider for each parent level links--*/
}
ul#topnav li a
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#topnav li:hover
{
    background: #1376c9 url(../images/topnav_active.gif) repeat-x;
}

ul#topnav li span
{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 35px;
    display: none; /*--Hide by default--*/
    width: 800px;
    background: #1376c9;
    color: #fff; /*--Bottom right rounded corner--*/
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /*--Bottom left rounded corner--*/
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
ul#topnav li:hover span
{
    display: block;
}
/*--Show subnav on hover--*/
ul#topnav li span a
{
    display: inline;
}
/*--Since we declared a link style on the parent list link, we will correct it back to its original state--*/
ul#topnav li span a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

---

.aspx

```
<div style="  margin-right:20%" >
            <ul id="topnav">
                <li><a href="frm_AssistantCV.aspx">الرئيسية</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">النشاط التعليمي</a> <span><a href="frm_TeachingLoad.aspx">العبأ التدريسي</a>
                    | <a href="frm_EducationalActivities.aspx">الأنشطة التعليمية</a> | <a href="frm_EducationalActivitiesDirectly.aspx">
                        الأنشطة التعليمية المباشرة</a> </span></li>
                <li><a href="#">النشاط العلمي</a> <span><a href="frm_ScientificActivity.aspx">النشاط
                    العلمي 1</a> | <a href="frm_ScientificActivity2.aspx">النشاط العلمي 2</a> | <a href="frm_ScientificActivity3.aspx">
                        النشاط العلمي 3</a> </span></li>
                <li><a href="frm_ManagementActivity.aspx">النشاط الاداري</a></li>
                <li><a href="frm_StudentActivities.aspx">االاشتراك في أنشطة طلابية</a></li>
                <li><a href="frm_Evaluation.aspx">التقييم العام</a></li>
                <li><a href="LoginPage.aspx">خروج</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I use this [menu](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/horizontal-sub-nav-with-css-jquery/)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to do two things, and it will solve your question !

1) Remove margin right from div.

```
Previous :<div style="  margin-right:20%" >

Modified: <div>
```

2) Update your topnav css as below :

```
ul#topnav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC6A11;
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is going to zoom but you can make it stick by replacing:

```
<div style="  margin-right:20%; width:100%" >
```

with

```
<div style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 20px;" >
```

Comment: I did. I don't fully understand your problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: sorry for my english.the problem happened when i zoom in or out or maximize and minimize the browser , the position of the menu changed . and this is so bad because i don't know how the setting of every user. try to zoom in or out(the browser  zoom , you will detect the probelm

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that you have your meta viewport tag in your HTML files should help, and 
setting the 'position' attribute to 'fixed' in your menu's CSS will make it sticky/float.

Comment: It would be even better if you add some lines of code along with your explanation